# Django API Blog-post

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

**models.py**

```
class CommentModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(PostModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class CommentListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CommentModel
        fields = ['id','comment','post','user','created_at']
```

**views.py**

```
class CommentListView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = CommentModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentListSerializer
```

can anyone help me to retrieve all the comments that are posted under a blog post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to instal django_filters but the following should work [doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#api-guide)

```py
class CommentListView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = CommentModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentListSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['post']
```

Comment: [Alombaros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20263044/alombaros) thank